# wp_query with multiple custom fields returning 0 results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

In wordpess 4.1 I have the following WP_Query:

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'ys_product',
        'orderby'        => array( 'date' ),
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'   => 'ys_product_status',
                'value' => 'ok'
            ),
            array (
                'key'   => 'ys_product_start',
                'value' => date('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array (
                'key'   => 'ys_product_end',
                'value' => date('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<='
            )
        )
    ) );
```

And on my DB I have two items with post_type 'ys_product', and with post_meta like this:

Item 1

- meta_key ys_product_status = 'ok'
- meta_key ys_product_start = '20141101'
- meta_key ys_product_end = '20141230'

Item 2

- meta_key ys_product_status = 'ok'
- meta_key ys_product_start = '20141101'
- meta_key ys_product_end = '20150131'

The result of date('Ymd') today is '20141226', which seems clearly between those boundaries.

But if I search only filtering by 'ys_product_status' == 'ok'; I get my two items. But when I add my two other meta, it wont return any results at all.

The contents of $products->request are:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  ysls_posts.ID
 FROM ysls_posts 
 INNER JOIN ysls_postmeta ON ( ysls_posts.ID = ysls_postmeta.post_id )
 INNER JOIN ysls_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( ysls_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
 INNER JOIN ysls_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( ysls_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
 AND ysls_posts.post_type = 'ys_product'
 AND (ysls_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR ysls_posts.post_status = 'private')
 AND ( 
  ( ysls_postmeta.meta_key = 'ys_product_status' AND CAST(ysls_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'ok'  ) 
   AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'ys_product_start' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '20141226' ) 
   AND 
  ( mt2.meta_key = 'ys_product_end' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) <= '20141226' )
 ) GROUP BY ysls_posts.ID  LIMIT 0, 8
```

The post_meta contents for the two posts I'm targeting:
[image: item 1] [image: item 2]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `var_dump($products->request);` give? Please add the SQL query to your question.

Comment: ys_product_start is never greater or equal than 20141226 - but you look for that.

Comment: It's official: I'm blind, or worse. :P Flipped those signs. Been looking at this code for a bit and couldn't see it. Sorry about that, and many thanks.

Comment: Your query is only searching for values where the start and end date is today, rather than falling between the 2 database values.  The comparisons are backwards.  You want to know where the current date >= start and current date <= end

Comment: Yes, just realized I had my signs flipped (thanks @hakre) Is it good manners to keep the question up if it's just a stupid typo, or should I delete it?

Comment: Well you could put (move) the part with how you obtained the SQL and how you could debug this then into an answer. And then turn the question title  into "How to debug Wordpress wp_query with multiple custom fields?" - That perhaps has some value then. Esp. as you have nice screenshots etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array (
'key'   => 'ys_product_start',
'value' => date('Ymd'),
'compare' => '>='
),
array (
'key'   => 'ys_product_end',
'value' => date('Ymd'),
'compare' => '<='
)
```

here:  ys_product_start >= date('Ymd') AND ys_product_end  <=  date('Ymd') its mean a row must met the **both** conditions but no one can

```
Row 1 NOT  20141101 >= 20141226 AND 20141230 <= 20141226 // false AND  false = false
meta_key ys_product_start = '20141101'
meta_key ys_product_end = '20141230'

Row 2 NOT 20141101 >= 20141226 AND 20150131 <= 20141226 // false AND false = false

meta_key ys_product_start = '20141101'
meta_key ys_product_end = '20150131'
```